# MySQL query help to fetch data combining two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following tables

**articles_category**

```
id    title    sef_title
```

**articles_data**

```
id    cat_id    title    sef_title    details
```

On each table "id" is the primary key and articles_data.cat_id is foreign key of articles_category

I need to fetch one latest article data for each articles category with following data.

```
articles_category.id
articles_category.title
articles_category.sef_title
articles_data.id
articles_data.cat_id
articles_data.title
articles_data.sef_title
articles_data.details
```

I tried with following query but it displays first article (oldest entry) rather than latest one.

```
SELECT
    articles_category.id as article_cat_id, articles_category.sef_title as cat_sef_title, articles_category.title as cat_title,
    articles_data.id, articles_data.cat_id as listing_cat_id, articles_data.title, articles_data.sef_title, articles_data.details
FROM articles_category, articles_data
WHERE articles_category.id = articles_data.cat_id
GROUP BY articles_data.cat_id
ORDER BY articles_data.id DESC
```

Comment: @lvan the table doesn't have any date field, what I need to sort is last article on each category

Comment: You should use a date, never trust in ID. You don't know what SQL engine is doing behind the scene :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's a one to many relation, try (untested):

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles_category, articles_data 
WHERE articles_category.id = articles_data.cat_id 
  AND articles_data.id in (
     SELECT max(articles_data.id) 
     FROM articles_data GROUP BY cat_id
  )
```

you are not guaranteed a particular row on a `GROUP BY`

and you should really use a date on your article as the max id is never guaranteed to be the latest article even if you are using autoincrement

Comment: this query seems to be working fine. I am not sure what you want to tell about "max id is never guaranteed to be the latest article even if you are using autoincrement". Can you give more info on that?

Comment: one can always insert an article at an id that was deleted at some point (which would not be latest)

Answer (score 0):

ORDER affects the display of records after the GROUP function has been performed. The GROUP function recognizes the first record it sees in its search.

What you need to do is perform 2 queries. The first one should be

```
SELECT max(articles_data.id), articles_data.cat_id ... 
GROUP BY articles_data.cat_id
```

The second query should fetch the associated records using those resultant primary keys.

Comment: in theory...yes. but, might be too slow for the purposes of the application in question.

Answer (score -1):

A possibility is to create another value such as date_created and place a time stamp there when creating an entry.

Then you would just have to `ORDER BY` date.

Comment: Ascending sort shows the lowest number at the top of the list. Your answer won't change his output.

Comment: id is auto_increment on both tables. I tried with both `ORDER BY articles_data.id ASC` and `ORDER BY articles_data.id DESC` but it doesn't work

Comment: Solution would be just to create a time stamp. It's always good to know when something was created.